# Jackson: Serialize and deserialize enum values as integers

Tags: java, json, serialization, enums, jackson

Consider the following enum and class:

```
public enum State {
    OFF,
    ON,
    UNKNOWN
}

public class Machine {
    String name;
    int numCores;
    State state;

    public Machine(String name, int numCores, State state) {
        this.name = name;
        this.numCores = numCores;
        this.state = state;
    }
}
```

And consider the following main function:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Machine m = new Machine("Machine 1", 8, State.OFF);
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String machineAsJsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(m);
    System.out.println(machineAsJsonString);
}
```

Currently, the output of this main is:

```
{"name" : "Machine 1", "numCores" : 8, "state" : "OFF"}
```

This output is not good for me, as instead of the string `"OFF"` for `state`, I would like it to be `0`, which is the ordinal value of `OFF` in the enum `State`.

**So the actual result I want to get is:**

```
{"name" : "Machine 1", "numCores" : 8, "state" : 0}
```

Is there some elegant way to make it behave this way?

Comment: My jab at an annotation free implementation. Do reply. http://pastebin.com/raw/Mvf9Ygq1

Comment: `ON = 0`, `OFF = 1`, does NOT look like a friendly thing IMHO ... just saying ;-)

Comment: @Julien it took me 4 years, but I've finally taken your advice and fixed it :P

Answer (score 90, accepted):

It should work by specifying `JsonValue` mapper.

```
public enum State {
    OFF,
    ON,
    UNKNOWN;

    @JsonValue
    public int toValue() {
        return ordinal();
    }
}
```

This works for deserialization also, as noted in Javadoc of `@JsonValue` annotation:

> NOTE: when use for Java enums, one additional feature is that value
> returned by annotated method is also considered to be the value to
> deserialize from, not just JSON String to serialize as. This is
> possible since set of Enum values is constant and it is possible to
> define mapping, but can not be done in general for POJO types; as
> such, this is not used for POJO deserialization

Comment: In fact, if you put a debug statement on `toValue()` method above, you'll notice that Jackson makes as many calls to `toValue()` as many ENUM values are.

Comment: This solution works only if we are dealing with enum ordinals. If enums have an integer field, `@JsonValue` fails to work and we need to declare a static method with `@JsonCreator` annotation to resolve the appropriate enum. Here is an open bug for the same - https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1850

Comment: Also it's possible to use Mixin for Enum, e.g. `interface EnumMixin { @JsonValue int ordinal(); }` - do not forget to register it in object mapper.

Answer (score 27):

You can use setting

```
objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_ENUMS_USING_INDEX);
```

See https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/test/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/TestEnumSerialization.java for complete test cases

Thanks to tip at https://righele.it/2016/01/30/jackson-deserialization-from-json-to-java-enums/

Comment: Excellent. This should be the accepted answer, less intrusive

Comment: It is more intrusive as affects ALL enums serialized by that ObjectMapper, so you lose ability to control it yourself...

Comment: do I need @JsonSerialize at enum file?

Answer (score 16):

You can use in this way

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER)
public enum State {
       OFF,
       ON,
       UNKNOWN
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Yet another way:

```
public enum State {

    @JsonProperty("0")
    OFF,

    @JsonProperty("1")
    ON,

    @JsonProperty("2")
    UNKNOWN
}
```

However, this will produce `{"state" : "1"}` instead of `{"state" : 1}` (string, not numeric). In most cases it's OK

Comment: It may work, but this also requires you to write `@JsonProperty` before each enum item and maintain the ordinal numbers by yourself. Implementing a method that just returns the ordinal, turns to be a much better practice and much more robust.

Comment: @SomethingSomething from the other hand placing a new enum value between, say, *OFF* and *UNKNOWN* (or deleting existing one) will break the ordinal-based behavior, so maintenance will be required anyway

Comment: That's right. Agreed that your answer is worth being posted

Answer (score 5):

For completion I post another way: custom serializer:

```
public class StateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<State> {  
    public void serialize(State value, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        generator.writeStartObject();
        generator.writeFieldName("id");
        generator.writeNumber(value.getId());
        generator.writeEndObject();
    }
}

@JsonSerialize(using = StateSerializer.class)
public enum State { 
    ...
    public int getId(){...}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print the ordinal of the enum you can change your constructor to accept an `int` instead of `State` and then in your call to `Machine` you can structure it in the following way:

`Machine m = new Machine("Machine 1", 8, State.OFF.ordinal());`

This will get the enum ordinal value of the passed in state and print the following

`{name='Machine 1', numCores=8, state=0}`

Comment: I like this workaround. I'll wait for other answers, as there might be more elegant ways to do it

Comment: @TomC your first line of code will prone to a compile time error because of argument (last) is integer in actual argument while Constructor having enum type actually .. Thank yo

Comment: @VikrantKashyap I specifically stated in my answer that that the constructor would have to be changed from a type of `State` to `int`

See: _change your constructor to accept an `int` instead of `State`_

Answer (score 0):

For integer enums, in kotlin, this works well. In java as well. If you don't want to use ordinals.

```
enum class State(@get:JsonValue val state: Int) {
          OFF(0),
          ON(1),
          UNKNOWN(-1)
}
```

Byte code generated is:

```
@JsonValue
public final int getState() {
  return this.state;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I had autogenerated enum classes, and could not add `@JsonValue` (or `@XmlValue`).
I resolved this with custom serialize method, where I added:

```
objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING);
```

Complete method was like this, for example:

```
private static ObjectMapper createXmlMapper() {
  ObjectMapper objectMapper = new XmlMapper();
  objectMapper.registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
  JacksonXmlModule xmlModule = new JacksonXmlModule();
  xmlModule.setDefaultUseWrapper(false);
  objectMapper.registerModule(xmlModule);
  objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
  objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING);  // to overcome jackson enum serialization issue, where enum name is returned instead of value
  objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
  return objectMapper;
}

// Method to serialize object to XML using XmlMapper
public static String serializeToXml(Object object) throws JsonProcessingException {
  ObjectMapper objectMapper = createXmlMapper();
  return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
}
```