# Nested enum with definition as String

Tags: java, enums

I'm facing a problem with nested enum. So, I have an nested enum which has default values as you can see. Before there were just an enums like CDs and CMs. Now I set something like definition to every of it as you can see "Cool Ds" and etc. Currently I'm facing a problem that I can't read enums String, which is in *()* and I don't know how to fix it anymore. Does anyone have an idea?

```
 package com.test.beans;

  import java.io.Serializable;
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;


@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class RecordBean implements Serializable {
public enum Types {
    CDs("Cool Ds"), CMs("Cool Ms");

   private final  String s;
   private Types(String s) {
        this.s=s;
    }

    public String getTypes(){
       return s;
    }
    public static Types fromNumeric(int index) {
        switch (index) {
            default:
                return null;
            case 0:
                return Types.CDs;
            case 1:
                return Types.CMs;

        }
    }

}


private Types type;

private float value;

public RecordBean() {
    // default constructor for default instantiate
}

public RecordBean(Types type, float value) {
    this.type = type;
    this.value = value;
}

public Types getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(Types type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public float getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(float value) {
    this.value = value;
}


}
```

**UPDATE**

Error what I'm getting:

```
    17/04/10 12:44:53 ERROR App$: Can not construct instance of com.test.beans.RecordBean$Types from String value 'Cool Ds': value not one of declared Enum instance names:  CDs, CMs ]
```

So as you can see he is not comparing my String  'Cool Ds' with enums String in brackets but with pure enum or *CDs* and *CMs*

My USE-CASE is like this. I'm working spark streaming where data are incoming to my RecordBean class and where are comparing to my *enum type*. Because in database are changed types from *CMs* to *Cool Ms* I needed to change the same in my app by adding definition to Enum. Afterwards I couldn't accomplish part where app will process enum like *CMs* and read its definition or *Cool Ms*

Comment: Unfortunately I have *no* idea what exactly you are asking ...

Comment: I update it and set **ERROR** maybe now it is clear? :)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Your updates help, but still just half of the things we might need.

Comment: Update no2, very well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jackson: Serialize and deserialize enum values as integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37833557/jackson-serialize-and-deserialize-enum-values-as-integers)

Comment: The dupe uses `int` but that's not different to your Strings.

Comment: Side note: the constructor `public RecordBean()` is not a default constructor, so its comment is wrong. The default constructor is the one provided by the compiler when the source doesn't provide one. The `RecordBean` provides two, therefore neither is a default constructor.

Comment: You don't show the code that tries to find the enum constant from a string. Show that code to get advice.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure, you can read with : CDs.getTypes() and CMs.getTypes()

Comment: Noup, I'm getting  `incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to com.test.beans.RecordBean.Types`

Answer (score 0):

*Guessing*: maybe the framework is calling toString() on your enum constants, thus you might want to add:

```
public enum Types {
 ...
 @Overrride 
 public String toString() { return s; }
```

In other words: make sure that your existing enum constants are really using that "new" changed string name.

But beyond that: consider stepping back and changing your overall design. Your problem isn't uncommon - enums are nice from a programming point of view (as in: using enum constants leads to cleaner code); but: they are **not** suited for persistence. Versioning with enums is hell.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware what you said about versioning but for now I just need prototype and afterwards I'll redesign whole app. 

Also, I tried your guess but the **ERROR** is still here

Comment: I guess you want to add a bunch of trace statements - like in each method of your enum ... just to see what is called; if there is anything that you could do easily. I am thinking of adding additional enum constants; probably using the **same** strings as CD and CM had originally.

Comment: Hmm, that's my original idea, I just want to return for example: "Cool Ds" but within enum otherwise I'll need to change lots of stuff which I don't need by now. 
I'll try with JSONValue annotation
If you think of any easily step to resolve this say :)

Comment: Be assured; if I had better ideas; I would have told you about already ;-(